# Querying using linq in EF6 is giving old values while database is having updated value

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

Querying using Linq in EF6 is giving old values while the database is having updated values
In the code below for the first run it works fine, But after the table `tblReferenceNumber` gets new rows, the query is returning only old values while I expect it to retrieve including the new records.

```
AuthDBEntities db = New AuthDBEntities()
tblReferenceNumber LRefNum = db.tblReferenceNumber.OrderByDescending(ab => ab.ID).First();
string lrNum = LRefNum.ReferenceNumber;
```

why I am getting the old values?
How can I fix it?

Comment: What is the generated SQL ? Did you try to execute generated SQL on your db developer tool ?

Comment: Create a fresh context to get data from DB again. There are many articles on "non-cached" EF.

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder how can i do it please? i am new

Comment: Your context usually have the suffix "Entities" or "Context". So, `using(var ctx = new MyEntities()) var first = ctx.First(something); using(var ctx2 = new MyEntities()) var updated = ctx2.First(something);`

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder i tried it is not working

Comment: Can you give us more code? Like the definition of "db"?

Comment: you question required more explanation, first of all when and how your table is updated ? Is it in your application ? is it in same request ? is it in between the runs ? 

then you have to show us what is inside that AuthDBEntities ? is it a dbcontext ? and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Each instance of `DbContext` has a cache. If you are using the same instance of `db` than the last time you got that record, then you will end up getting the cached data.

You can use:

```
db.Entry(LRefNum).Reload();
```

to force it to get fresh data.

More info about the caching here: http://codethug.com/2016/02/19/Entity-Framework-Cache-Busting/

But that also raises the question of why you are getting the same record twice with the same instance of `db`. Did you perhaps declare `db` as static?

Comment: thank you i tied `db.Entry(LRefNum).Reload()`, unfortunately not working. similar issue

Comment: How are you declaring `db`?

Answer (score -1):

When you use .First() you materialize this query and load data into memory. 
So when u try to get values from LRefNum you refer to data in memory instead of database.

Comment: How can I fix it?

Comment: While you have IQueryable you just building your query and when you use .First(), .FirstOrDefault(), ToList() etc. you materialize query and hit the database.
You have to write new query to database, and dont forget about db.SaveChanges() after updating your data.

Comment: there is `db.SaveChanges() ` in the create action method, what do you mean write new query?

Comment: Yes, but i said when he put data to object (LRefNum) which came from database with .First() method, then every refer to this object will get data from memory. Dude, read about materialization.